Dryer vent issue
Gas dryer worked fine this AM. Later, we eplaced outside vent cap & did a bit of vacuuming in the duct at the end.  Now, no hot air (neither heat nor air) coming out at outside vent. Dryer is getting hot, but now perhaps too hot. Too much of a coincidence that it would stop working after we did this. We had to have done something to cause this. Could we have dislodged that much of a potential blockage back down the duct? Also, could this be from a gap in the vent cap seal or a crack/tear in the duct? Completely stumped & not sure who to call. Is this an appliance repair or duct cleaning/repair? Thank you!

What happens if you remove the vent cap? If nothing changes then you need to check the entire vent pipe. Maybe even clean the dryer filter.

Does the vent cap have a cover that closes when not in use?  If so was it put in the right way and is it opening?
